# Create two threads in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, network-programming

I am very new to Xcode and Objective-C, so I don't really know what I am doing yet! ;-)
Basically I want to have an IPhone Application that can run possibly two threads, which will later use `UDP Sockets` to communicate with other Apps.

I have put functions to react when the `start-Thread/stop-Thread` Button in the UI are pressed, now I want to fill them with code to actually create and start the threads.

- What would be the correct procedure here?
- Do I need to subclass    `NSThread`?
- Where do I implement the code, that the new threads will execute?

  I can't see a run method, or something similar. I suppose that has something to do with the **`selector`**, which I don't understand.

Comment: Read the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [NSThread reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you subclass `NSThread`, you would typically override the `main` method.

Comment: I suggest you use [dispatch queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) instead.

Comment: Modern iOS code should not be using NSThread, there are much better alternatives.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [dispatch queues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24). They're essentially lightweight threads for which you don't need to worry about the threading or queueing directly.

```
-(void) spawn
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [self doWorkInBackground];
    });
}
```

You can use one of the built-in queues or your own.

And you should probably read up on [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html) too, in particular the memory management aspect.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, I started reading the guide. However, as far as I understand it now, we can have serial or concurrent queues. In serial ones, only one task is executed at any time, which is not sufficient for me, since there might be two tasks concurrently. So I would need a concurrent queue, were however the system manages how many tasks run parallely. I however need to run exactly the two tasks, when the user requires them. In general however I would need to create 2 Blocks or functions each executing one "thread" and put them in a queue?

Comment: Since blocks are written inline with the rest of the code, and I would need to have one block for each thread and the threads are not soo short, I wonder if thats really the right way to go, considering code-overview.

Comment: You can declare blocks out of line just fine

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)performBlockInBackground:(void (^)())block {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        block();
    });
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
[self performBlockInBackground:^{
    NSLog(@"Log from background");
}];
```

Comment: That method will crash if you don't check if the block is not NULL.

Comment: @danielbeard Yes of course, but why on earth would you call `[self performBlockInBackground:NULL];`?

Comment: If the block is stored on a different object and it is deallocated, the block will be NULL. E.g. `someObject.actionBlock`

Comment: @danielbeard Yes of course, you can do that. But that's really an exception.

Comment: Nope, it's a best practice. ANY time you call a block, you should check it's not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty deep discussion, but Apple's "[Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)" should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider using [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html). It uses dispatch queues under the hood, but offers higher-level API and possibility to cancel ongoing operation (which might be helpful for you).